# How to use .htaccess to rewrite all pages to a simple URL?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have the following situation. I want to point all URLs like this:

```
http://localhost/mypage
```

To a long URL, just like this:

```
http://localhost/index.php?&page=mypage
```

And then in PHP do something like this:

```
include 'pages/' . $_GET['page'] . '.php';
```

I have tried the following but I get some errors.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?&page=$1 [NC]
```

Is there any way to do this without listing all pages in .htaccess file?

Comment: It's weird. It tries to load `pages/index.php.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

So if you request **http://example.com/about**, it will be re-written as **http://example.com/index.php?page=about**.

I’d also suggest doing some validation on `$_GET['page']` in your **index.php** script too, as people will be able to navigation your file system otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
# This line starts the mod_rewrite module
RewriteEngine on

# If the request is for a file that already exists on the server
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Pass all trafic through the index file (if the requested file doesn't exist)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

/project/1 will be the same as `$_GET['project'] = 1`

Comment: Thanks but now I have another problem. My website now don't load Javascript and CSS correctly. There's something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your First Line Should Be:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Then Use

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Instead of

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?&page=$1 [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ index.php?&page=$1 [QSA]
```